# Show all image in sdcard with MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID

Tags: android, thumbnails

I use below method to view image in gridview.
 [Reference](http://wang-peng1.iteye.com/blog/676010)

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};  
Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

It show the image which had thumbnail in sdcard.
But I want to show all the images in sdcard, not only the thumbnail exist one.
Is there any method to make the Android System to create the thumbnail for MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, the url `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` can return all images,
and then `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` has method:

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnail (ContentResolver cr, long origId, long groupId, int kind, BitmapFactory.Options options)
// origid  is the Images.ImageColumns._ID
//groupid is the Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID
```

can return the thumbnails.